# Dont show $_GET variable in URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
 forum_id forum_name
    1        stuff
    2        stuff
    3        stuff
```

i have above table `forum`. `forum.php` calls it like `forum.php?forum_id=?` Now i have written a mod_rewrite for `forum.php`

```
 RewriteRule ^forum/([0-9]+)$ forum.php?forum_id=$1 [L]
```

After that my url looks like `example.com/forum/4`. However i want my url to show `forum_name` not `forum_id` like `example.com/forum/stuff`. What can i do for this thing. I am gonna get `forum table` with `forum_id` because its the right method. But this time how i am gonna know what is writing inside stuff, and show it to user? I dont know if i can explain it correctly. Thanks for help

Comment: It appears the way your software is setup, is it looks for the forum name by `ID`.  In order to use /forum/stuff, you have to modify the code to look for it in the DB from the name and not `ID`. Careful though as that can get tricky if there are duplicate names. FYI,There is nothing wrong with using ID in URL. Look at Stackoverflows URL's.

Comment: @anubhava My question maybe it can show `$_GET['forum_name']` variable while not showing `$_GET['forum_id']`

Comment: @PanamaJack Yeah they basically calling db like i do. But how they add `question name` to near the number?

Comment: I could be wrong, but this site fetches the question (or answer or post) by ID only. The name is just to improve SEO. So the template would output the name in the URL, even though it is not being used.

Comment: And just to add to that, if you strip out the name from the URL being requested, the system adds it back. You may wish to follow this methodology instead.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change your matching pattern:

```
# Match anything after "forum/" that's not a slash
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+) forum.php?forum_name=$1 [L]
```

And after that of course you need to change the database query in your PHP to select the forum by `forum_name` instead of `forum_id`.

Comment: as i stated in my question i want to call db with `forum_id` but i want to show `forum_name` that corresponds it. Thats the question.

Comment: @WebberDepor Then you should follow [Mike's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157694/dont-show-get-variable-in-url-with-htaccess/35158077#comment58034780_35157694) and let your template append `forum_name` to the URL. You can use your original rewrite pattern for that (just get rid of the `$`).